# If G is a compact semisimple Lie group and Z is its center, is G/Z always compact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

The title pretty much sums up the question: Suppose $G$ is a compact semisimple Lie group with center $Z$, The question is if $G/Z$ is always compact? or, under which conditions will it be compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any quotient of any compact topological group is compact, because the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.